# Finding corresponding values between 2 matrices

Tags: r, matrix

I have 2 matrices:

Matrix - `test_nodes`:

```
head (test_nodes)

   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
1  9 17 32 35 20 35 41 40  9 48
2  9 14  8  8 16 16 14 13  4  9
3 24 17 21 35 20 35 33 48  9 48
4  9 14  8  8 16 16 14 13  4  9
5  9 30  8  8 16 16 14 20  4  9
6 42 38  6 12 50 13 36 44 51 13
```

Matrix - `NAMETRANS`:

```
head (NAMETRANS)

   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,] 6    5    4    8    8    8    4    5    4    8    
[2,] 8    8    6    11   14   13   10   6    9    9    
[3,] 9    13   8    12   16   16   12   12   11   10   
[4,] 12   14   15   14   18   23   14   13   14   13   
[5,] 17   16   21   16   19   26   17   17   18   16   
[6,] 20   17   22   17   20   28   18   18   19   20 


> NAMETRANS
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,] 6    5    4    8    8    8    4    5    4    8    
 [2,] 8    8    6    11   14   13   10   6    9    9    
 [3,] 9    13   8    12   16   16   12   12   11   10   
 [4,] 12   14   15   14   18   23   14   13   14   13   
 [5,] 17   16   21   16   19   26   17   17   18   16   
 [6,] 20   17   22   17   20   28   18   18   19   20   
 [7,] 21   20   23   18   21   29   19   20   20   22   
 [8,] 22   23   25   24   22   30   23   21   21   25   
 [9,] 23   25   29   26   23   31   24   22   23   27   
[10,] 24   26   30   28   24   32   27   24   24   28   
[11,] 30   28   31   32   27   33   30   26   28   29   
[12,] 32   30   32   34   29   35   32   28   32   31   
[13,] 35   31   33   35   31   36   33   32   34   32   
[14,] 36   33   35   37   32   37   35   33   36   34   
[15,] 38   36   37   38   34   38   36   34   37   36   
[16,] 40   37   40   39   37   41   38   39   39   37   
[17,] 41   38   41   40   39   42   41   40   42   38   
[18,] 42   40   42   41   44   43   42   43   43   41   
[19,] 44   41   43   43   45   45   44   44   44   43   
[20,] 46   42   45   44   46   46   45   45   45   45   
[21,] 47   43   46   46   47   47   46   46   46   48   
[22,] 48   44   48   47   48   48   48   48   47   49   
[23,] 49   46   50   49   49   49   49   50   48   51   
[24,] 50   47   51   50   50   50   50   51   49   52   
[25,] 51   NULL 52   51   53   51   51   52   51   53   
[26,] 53   NULL 53   52   54   52   52   53   52   54   
[27,] 55   NULL 54   55   55   53   53   54   54   55   
[28,] 56   NULL 57   56   57   NULL NULL 55   56   56   
[29,] 58   NULL 58   57   58   NULL NULL NULL 57   57   
[30,] 59   NULL 59   NULL 59   NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL
```

I would like to create a third matrix `TRANSNAMES`.
NAMETRANS will go through each column in `test_nodes` and will replace the value in the cell with the value of the row number in the relevant column. For instance, for the `9` value it is in the column `1` in test_nodes and is the row number 3 in `NAMETRANS` so it will get value 3 in `TRANSNAMES`.

```
TRANSNAMES [1,1] = 3
TRANSNAMES [2,1] = 3
```

(also 9) etc.

```
Here is the result, something is wrong:
> transnames
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
 [1,] 3    NULL 12   NULL 6    NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL 
 [2,] 3    NULL 3    NULL 3    NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL 
 [3,] 10   NULL 5    NULL 6    NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL 
 [4,] 3    NULL 3    NULL 3    NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL 
 [5,] 3    NULL 3    NULL 3    NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL 
 [6,] 18   NULL 2    NULL 24   NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL 
 [7,] 24   NULL 8    NULL 24   NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL 
 [8,] 10   NULL 5    NULL 15   NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL 
 [9,] 19   NULL 8    NULL 24   NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL 
[10,] 10   NULL 5    NULL 6    NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL 
[11,] 3    NULL 16   NULL 6    NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL 
[12,] 10   NULL 5    NULL 6    NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL 
[13,] 12   NULL 18   NULL 10   NULL NULL NULL NULL NULL
>dput(test_nodes)
...
  c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10")))
   1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
1  9 17 32 35 20 35 41 40  9 48
2  9 14  8  8 16 16 14 13  4  9
3 24 17 21 35 20 35 33 48  9 48
4  9 14  8  8 16 16 14 13  4  9
5  9 30  8  8 16 16 14 20  4  9
6 42 38  6 12 50 13 36 44 51 13
```

>

```
 dput(NAMETRANS)
structure(list(6, 8, 9, 12, 17, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 30, 32, 35, 
    36, 38, 40, 41, 42, 44, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 53, 55, 56, 
    58, 59, 5, 8, 13, 14, 16, 17, 20, 23, 25, 26, 28, 30, 31, 
    33, 36, 37, 38, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 46, 47, NULL, NULL, NULL, 
    NULL, NULL, NULL, 4, 6, 8, 15, 21, 22, 23, 25, 29, 30, 31, 
    32, 33, 35, 37, 40, 41, 42, 43, 45, 46, 48, 50, 51, 52, 53, 
    54, 57, 58, 59, 8, 11, 12, 14, 16, 17, 18, 24, 26, 28, 32, 
    34, 35, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 43, 44, 46, 47, 49, 50, 51, 52, 
    55, 56, 57, NULL, 8, 14, 16, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 
    27, 29, 31, 32, 34, 37, 39, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 53, 
    54, 55, 57, 58, 59, 8, 13, 16, 23, 26, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 
    33, 35, 36, 37, 38, 41, 42, 43, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 
    52, 53, NULL, NULL, NULL, 4, 10, 12, 14, 17, 18, 19, 23, 
    24, 27, 30, 32, 33, 35, 36, 38, 41, 42, 44, 45, 46, 48, 49, 
    50, 51, 52, 53, NULL, NULL, NULL, 5, 6, 12, 13, 17, 18, 20, 
    21, 22, 24, 26, 28, 32, 33, 34, 39, 40, 43, 44, 45, 46, 48, 
    50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, NULL, NULL, 4, 9, 11, 14, 18, 19, 
    20, 21, 23, 24, 28, 32, 34, 36, 37, 39, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 
    47, 48, 49, 51, 52, 54, 56, 57, NULL, 8, 9, 10, 13, 16, 20, 
    22, 25, 27, 28, 29, 31, 32, 34, 36, 37, 38, 41, 43, 45, 48, 
    49, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, NULL), .Dim = c(30L, 10L))
```

Comment: How about e.g., 24 and 42 in the first column of `test_nodes`? That is, does `NAMETRANS` contain all entires of `test_nodes`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do in `base`:

```
for(j in 1:ncol(transnames)){
  for(i in 1:nrow(transnames)){
    tryCatch(transnames[i,j] <- which(nametrans[,j]==test_nodes[i,j]),
             error = function(e) return(NA))
  }
}
> transnames
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    3    6   NA   NA    6   NA   NA   NA    2    NA
[2,]    3    4    3    1    3    3    4    4    1     2
[3,]   NA    6    5   NA    6   NA   NA   NA    2    NA
[4,]    3    4    3    1    3    3    4    4    1     2
[5,]    3   NA    3    1    3    3    4   NA    1     2
[6,]   NA   NA    2    3   NA    2   NA   NA   NA     4
```

As [989](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1505504/989) already mentioned, you are not providing information on what the matrix should contain if the value is not found in the respective column of nametrans, so this loop just returns `NA` for those values.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ben T. I get the right results for the first column but something is wrong for the second column. Please see my edit in the question body.

Comment: I think this is because the elements of one of the matrix is num while the other are int.

Comment: It would be best if you would provide our data using `dput`, see also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example
e. g. for your data `dput(test_nodes)`. then post the resulting string (beginning with `structure(` here.
You can also coerce your "num" (I believe you mean double or so) type matrix with `storage.mode(x) <- "integer"`
However, `NULL` as a result looks pretty strange to me

Comment: ,Please find the dput in the question body.

Comment: I think I found why. The last values of some of the columns is NULL. Maybe this cause the problem. How can I fix it? In addition, why does it make a mess?

Comment: how do you create the nametrans matrix? you should consider changing this so you do not end up with a list type containing NULLS

Comment: Thanks. I initialized it with 0L and it solved the problem.